# Calling the superclass' constuctor twice in the subclass' constructor

Tags: c++

I have a user defined class, say A. I have another user defined class B which publicly extends A.

When I define the constructor of B, I have to call the constructor of A in the member initializer list of B's constructor, or else the compiler will call the default constructor.

```
class A {
    int a;
public:
    A(int x = 0) {
        a = x;
    }
};

class B : public A {
    int b;
public:
    B(int x = 0) : A(2*x) {
        b = x;
    }
};
```

Now, I understand the logic behind all this. However, what I want to know is what happens when I do this instead:

```
class A {
    int a;
public:
    A(int x = 0) {
        a = x;
    }
};

class B : public A {
    int b;
public:
    B(int x = 0) {
        A(2*x);
        b = x;
    }
};
```

I mean, we all know that the compiler will call the default constructor of A before it enters the body of the B's constructor. Now, the first line of B's constructor body is to call another constructor of A (which takes arguments). So, what does this result in? Two different  constructors of the superclass are getting called here whenever an object of the subclass is being created. Please explain what happens...whether two objects will be created or what.

Comment: `A(2*x);` does not do what you expect - get used to member initializer lists!

Comment: *"whether two objects will be created or what."* - the constructor **does not** create an object; the constructor prepares the object for usage. The object is already created when the constructor runs.

Comment: You're reading too much into this.  You have entered the body of a function (You have gone past the first `{`).  What happens when you declare an object within a function and do nothing with it?  That is what you're doing here -- the rules don't change just because the function just happens to be a constructor.  The object created is temporary and then destroyed after that line is executed.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Just to be clear, what you're saying is that in the second version of the code, what the first line inside the B's constructor does is **create a new instance of A with no handle and that instance gets destroyed as soon as the control exits the B's constructor body**, is it?

Comment: @BloodBrother The instance of A inside the body of the constructor does a complete round trip of construction/destruction on that same line -- that's why it is temporary.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Oh man...why is that so? I thought it's lifetime was within the scope of the B's constructor body. What is the difference between the lifetimes of `A a(10)` and `A(10)`?

Comment: @BloodBrother With `A(10)` where is the object to destroy later on?  No different than if you did this: `int(8 + 1);`  This is legal C++.  So what happened to the value of 9?  Where did it go? Same with your `A(10)`.  That `A` object goes up in smoke right away.

Comment: BTW, I thought the garbage collector would collect them at the end of the program but I had no idea that it would collect such temporary objects as soon as the statement creating them ends.

Comment: @BloodBrother C++ is not Java.  There is no "garbage collection" done here.  C++ has deterministic destructors.

Comment: Now, I get it. You're the man. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3):

That doesn't call the constructor for the `A` subobject of the `B` being initialised. Instead, it creates and destroys a temporary object of type `A`. The only way to call the constructor of the base subobject is through the initialiser list, as in the first example.

Answer (score 2):

> Now, the first line of B's constructor body is to call another constructor of A (which takes arguments). So, what does this result in?

It constructs a temporary `A` and the temporary object is discarded right away. That call has no relationship to initializing the `A` part of `B`.